# C# dataGridView Control to show Multiplication Table

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need help regarding c# win Form application. I trying to achieve that to show a Multiplication Table or Times Table in a GridViewControl of win Form. loop iteration is defined with user input textbox control.
The problem is occurring the data is only added to the first column of gridViewControl where as i want to display the data in each cell of the gridViewControl.

Below is the code im using to achieve above mentioned result.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        string selection = comboBox1.SelectedText;
        int tblNo = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        int limit = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

        for( int i = 1; i <= limit; i++)
        {
            int res = i * tblNo;
            dt.Columns.Add("",typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add(tblNo + " x " + i + "=" + res);

        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


    }
```

**Result of above mentioned Code**
[image: Result of above mentioned Code]

**Required Result**
[image: Required Result]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: To provide values for multiple columns you need to pass array of values to the `datagridview.Rows.Add`; `datagridview.Rows.Add(new[] { "first", "second", third" });`

Comment: Could you please elaborate more

i have also tried foreach but nothing happend

Comment: Your `i` loop variable rightfully ought to be named `row` because it is acting on 1 row per iteration.  You need a `col` loop as well.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Sir you see in my code, Columns are being added in the gridView. Without Columns no rows can be added and with variable limit all columns are perfectly added with respect to the user defined input value containing int limit variable. I tried an inner loop as per your comment but it is adding more columns than the limit variable because of inner loop and also tried for each loop but getting required result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required Result can be achieved by iterating dataGridView Control Row element in a for loop and within for loop for-each loop can be used to fill same content in each cell of Row element. Below code i used to get required result set.

```
for(int i=0; i<any Integer;i++)
{
  foreach(DataGridViewCell gvCell in yourgridViewControl.Rows[i].Cells)
   {
      gvCell.Value = any string;
   }
}
```